# Proving that $2-2 \cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2^{n-1}}\right) = 4 \sin^2\left(\frac{\alpha}{2^n}\right)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How could I prove that $2-2 \cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2^{n-1}}\right) = 4 \sin^2\left(\frac{\alpha}{2^n}\right)$ using simple calculus relations? I've tried plugging in everything I found relevant in the course, but I don't get there.

Comment: What have you tried "plugging in", which I would guess would have been various values of $\alpha, n$?  What approaches have you found relevant in the course.  In general, please show your workings of what you did, in fact try.

Comment: Divide by 4 both sides and substitute $\alpha=2^nx$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use that $$\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2(x)$$

Comment: Thanks, that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$
\frac{\alpha}{2^{n}}= \frac{1}{2}\frac{\alpha}{2^{n-1}}
$$

and use bisection formulas.

Comment: i think it is $$\frac{\alpha}{2^{n-1}}=\frac{\alpha}{2^n\cdot 2^{-1}}=\frac{2\alpha}{2^n}$$

Comment: Yes, But it is the same !

Comment: yes it is the same

Comment: Thanks, that helped.